# How can I express a foreign key as a pair in Django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Here are some Django models:

```
class User (Model):
    name = CharField (max_length=100)

class ThingVersion (Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField (auto_now_add = True)

class ThingPartition (Model):
    version          = ForeignKey (ThingVersion)
    partition_number = IntegerField ()

class UserInPartition (Model):
    user             = ForeignKey (User)
    version          = ForeignKey (ThingVersion)
    partition_number = IntegerField ()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'version'))
```

I have deliberately ***not*** done the "obvious" thing, which is this

```
class UserInPartition (Model):
    user      = ForeignKey (User)
    partition = ForeignKey (ThingPartition)
```

because I require the `unique_together` constraint, which AFAIK isn't possible to express if I use the more-normalized `partition = ForeignKey (ThingPartition)` approach.

How do I express that the `UserInPartition.(version,partition_number)` pair is a foreign key to `ThingPartition`?

> Alternatively, is there a way to use the normalized `partition = ForeignKey (ThingPartition)` approach and constrain the `UserInPartition` model to only have one `partition_number` per `(user,version)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the goal you want to achieve to offer better answer. Why do you have partition number on both user in partition and thingpartition?

But what you could do is to turn ThingPartition into Through model for many to many relation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Basically using through model would do exactly what you want-

- have one model, where you refer to user in partition, partition number and version
- enforce unique together for all 3 things in this model

Basically, your setup would look something like this:

```
class User (Model):
    name = CharField (max_length=100)
    something_that_makes_sense = ManyToManyField(ThingVersion, through=ThingPartition)

class ThingVersion (Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField (auto_now_add = True)

class ThingPartition (Model):
    user             = ForeignKey (User)
    version          = ForeignKey (ThingVersion)
    partition_number = IntegerField ()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'version', 'partition_number')
```

That would be my best offer based on the limited knowledge i have.

Comment: The partition number is in ThingPartition because that defines the partition as some number of sets. The partition number appears separately in UserInPartition because that identifies which set (of a given partition) the User is in. Users can be partitioned in multiple ways simultaneously.